# Laravel 4 , adding custom validation using extend

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to use the Extend function that the validation offer, 
Here is what I have:

1). HomeController.php :

```
  $rules = array(
                    'first_name'=>'required|regex:/^[a-z ,."-]+$/i|min:2',
                    'last_name'=>'required|regex:/^[a-z ,."-]+$/i|min:2',
                    'gender'=>'required|alpha|gendercheck',
                    'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email,'.Input::get('id').',id',
                    'zip'=>'required|zipcheck|max:10',

                    );
```

2). Then to use the extend method I add it to routes.php:

```
    Validator::extend('zipcheck', function($field,$value,$parameters){
    // List of regular expressions to use, if a custom one isn't specified.
    $countryRegs = array(
          "US"=>"/^[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})?$/",
          "GB"=>"/^(GIR|[A-Z]\d[A-Z\d]??|[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z\d]??)[ ]??(\d[A-Z]{2})$/",
          "DE"=>"/\b((?:0[1-46-9]\d{3})|(?:[1-357-9]\d{4})|(?:[4][0-24-9]\d{3})|(?:[6][013-9]\d{3}))\b/",
          "CA"=>"/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/",
          "FR"=>"/^(F-)?((2[A|B])|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}$/",
          "IT"=>"/^(V-|I-)?[0-9]{5}$/",
          "AU"=>"/^(0[289][0-9]{2})|([1345689][0-9]{3})|(2[0-8][0-9]{2})|(290[0-9])|(291[0-4])|(7[0-4][0-9]{2})|(7[8-9][0-9]{2})$/",
          "NL"=>"/^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?([a-zA-Z]{2})?$/",
          "ES"=>"/^([1-9]{2}|[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])[0-9]{3}$/",
          "DK"=>"/^([D-d][K-k])?( |-)?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$/",
          "SE"=>"/^(s-|S-){0,1}[0-9]{3}\s?[0-9]{2}$/",
          "BE"=>"/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}$/"
    ); 

    // get country submitted..
    $country = Input::get('country');

    // check country if in the array..
    if (key_exists($country , $countryRegs))
        return preg_match($countryRegs[$country], $value);  
    else // other countries make sure no special characters in there
        return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9- ]+$/i' , $value);

    });
```

The problem is I want to keep my code organized and I dont want to add the validation extend to my routes.php

What is the best way where I can have those in its own class and call those from my HomeController and still it will work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. The way I like is make a file `/app/validators.php` (So it is in the same location as routes.php and `filters.php`)

Then go to app/start/global.php and add this at the bottom after the filters require:

```
require app_path().'/validators.php';
```

You can now declare all your extended validators in the `validators.php` file -and Laravel will use them.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in my project. I have a directory `app/extras` that contains functions for things like validators, singletons, and filters.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do. Personally I like to extends validation by a `ValidationService` (I think it is much cleaner).

**1)** We assume you use PSR-4 to load you own company directory in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "app/Acme"
        }
        ...
    },
}
```

You have to run `composer dumpautoload`.

**2)** Create your validation service provider:

*app/Acme/Extension/Validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Extension\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
    }

    public function boot() {
        $this->app->validator->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
            return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
    }

}
```

**3)** Register your service provider in `app/config/app.php` for autoloading:

```
<?php

return array(
    'providers' => array(
        ...
        'Acme\Extension\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
    ),
);
```

**4)** Create your custom validation rule(s):

*app/Acme/Extension/Validation/CustomValidator.php*

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Extension\Validation;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as IlluminateValidator;

class CustomValidator extends IlluminateValidator {

    public function validateAlphaNumSpace($attribute, $value) {
        return preg_match('/^([a-z\x20])+$/i', $value);
    }

    public function validateZip($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**5)** You are ready to use your custom rule(s). For example if I want to use my `AlphaNumSpace` rule (useful in many cases because original AlphaNum rule doesn't allow space!):

```
$rules = [
    'name'    => 'required|alpha_num_space',
    'zipcode' => 'required|zip',
];
```

Comment: I cannot stress enough: **you must run `php artisan dump-autoload`**.

Comment: Yes, that's the most important! How many times I forgot to re-run this command!